# MySQL query code syntax error in OpenCart

Tags: php, mysql, syntax, opencart

I don't know why I have error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught Exception: Error: You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server
>   version for the right syntax to use near '* FROM mydatabase_customer
>   SET status='0' WHERE customer_id='11'' at line 1
> Error No:
>   1064
> INSERT INTO * FROM mydatabase_customer SET status='0' WHERE
>   customer_id='11' in
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/system/library/db/mysqli.php:40
>   Stack trace: #0
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/system/library/db.php(45):
>   DB\MySQLi->query('INSERT INTO * F...') #1
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/catalog/controller/account/success.php(29):
>   DB->query('INSERT INTO * F...') #2
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/system/engine/action.php(79):
>   ControllerAccountSuccess->index() #3
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/catalog/controller/startup/router.php(25):
>   Action->execute(Object(Registry)) #4
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/system/eng in
>   /home/nedas/domains/mypage.com/public_html/opencart/system/library/db/mysqli.php
>   on line 40

My code:

```
        if ($this->customer->isLogged()) {
        $status = '0';
        $id = $this->customer->getId();
        $this->db->query("INSERT INTO * FROM perkulenkijoje_customer SET status='$status' WHERE customer_id='$id'");
        echo ("Info: Insert done");
    } else {
        echo ("Info: Please log in");
    }
```

Please help me.

How to successfully insert to database using opencart platform?

Comment: `INSERT INTO *` is not a thing. The syntax is `INSERT [INTO] tbl_name`, you can not use a wildcard instead of the table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to keep opencart db structure (I mean prefix) you need to use query like this

```
$this->db->query("UPDATE " . DB_PREFIX . "perkulenkijoje_customer SET status = '" . (int)$status . "' WHERE customer_id = '" . (int)$id . "'");
```

And better if this query you move to model file and call it in controller.

Answer (score 0):

Look like you want to `UPDATE` the data not doing `INSERT`, it should be like this :

`$this->db->query("UPDATE perkulenkijoje_customer SET status='$status' WHERE customer_id='$id'");`

Answer (score 0):

if you want change a value you should use update

```
     UPDATE perkulenkijoje_customer
     SET status='$status' WHERE customer_id='$id'
```

anyway you should not use php var in sql  you are at risk for sqlinjection  .. for this take a look at prepared  statement and binding parm for you db driver